# Gradient on $SU(n)$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, oc.optimization-and-control

I'm trying to calculate the gradient (wrt to the bi-invariant metric) of the following functions $F_1, F_2 : SU(n) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $F_1(U) = | Tr (G^{\dagger} U) |^2$, $F_2(U) = \Re (Tr (G^{\dagger} U)) $ where $G \in SU(n)$ is given.

Can there be a coordinate free expression for $\nabla F$?

(Posted here after no answer on MSE).

Comment: Gradient requires a choice of metric.  Do you mean to put, say, a bi-invariant metric on $SU(n)$?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I do mean using the bi-invariant metric.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the" bi-invariant metric, of course.  I would rewrite the question by including the actual choice or, better still, asking for $dF$ instead, which is independent of the choice of metric.  Also, what would you understand by coordinate-independent?  Do you want $dF$ as a function of $G$ and $U$?

Comment: There is freedom upto a constant multiple right? This will only affect the gradient upto a constant also which is not relevant in the application I have in mind. $\nabla F$ is really what I need and I'd like to avoid putting any coordinates in the group if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a calculation for the derivative $DF$ (or the differential $dF$), which does not depend on the metric.

Define $f:SU(n)\to\mathbb C$ by $f(U)=Tr(G^\dagger U)$.
If we think of $f$ being defined on all of $\mathbb C^{n\times n}$, then it is linear and $Df(U)(H)=f(H)$ for any matrix $H$.
If we restrict our attention to $SU(n)$, we need to choose $H$ from the tangent space at $U$.
If we identify this with the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ by left multiplication ($H\in\mathfrak{su}(n)$ is identified with $UH\in U\mathfrak{su}(n)=T_USU(n)$), we get the derivative $Df(U):\mathfrak{su}(n)\to\mathbb C$ defined by $Df(U)H=f(UH)=Tr(G^\dagger UH)$.

The function $F_2$ is just the real part of $f$, so its derivative is the real part of the derivative: $DF_2(U)=\Re(Tr(G^\dagger U \cdot))$.
The function $F_1$ is $f$ composed with $\phi:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$, given by $\phi(z)=|z|^2$.
Since $D\phi(z)w=2\Re(\bar wz)$, we get
$$
DF_1(U)(H)
=
D\phi(f(U))Df(U)H
=
2\Re(\overline{Tr(G^\dagger U)}Tr(G^\dagger UH)).
$$
In other words, the derivative is
$$
DF_1(U)=2\Re(\overline{Tr(G^\dagger U)}Tr(G^\dagger U\cdot)).
$$

Comment: Thanks for that. So, I'd got to $Tr(G^{\dagger}UH)$ also. How do I get from there to the gradient $\nabla F_1$?

Comment: @Benjamin, using the chain rule. Since $F_1=\phi\circ f$, we have $DF_1(U)=D\phi(f(U))Df(U)$. We know the derivatives of $f$ and $\phi$. For me at least it is easier to think of them as derivatives than as gradients, so that the chain rule looks the same no matter what the spaces are. If you want to calculate the derivative of $\phi$, it might be easier to work in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: This answer is worth a look: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1357102/161684